# Push older text while fading in new text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like new text, as it is fading in, to push the older text down instead of having new text appear after old text. Is this possible? Have been having a lot of difficulty figuring this out.

Here is the javascript:

```
var $el= $('.fader').map(function() {
  return this;
}).get();

$el.forEach(function (eachdiv){



var  text = $(eachdiv).text(),
words = text.split(".");
var html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    html += "<span>" + words[i] + " </span>" + '<br/>';
        $(eachdiv).html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
           return $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(200);

        });        
    }
});
```

The solution does seem to involve the use of prepend, but I'm not sure where to place prepend within the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try For loop like this instead of yours. Just Giving you an idea. give fadeIn effect as per your data arrives.

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        html.prepend("<span>" + words[i] + " </span>" + '<br/>');
            $(eachdiv).html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
               return $(this).fadeIn(200);

            });        
        }
```

Comment: This does change the order to the words, but it does not make newer words appear before older words. So the next words in line fadeIn to the position occupied by the previous word and the previous word gets moved to the next spot.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not understanding because I just see the words in flipped order.

Comment: Updated answer please check now and let me know if it works

Comment: Updated answer unfortunately did not work, it wasn't fading in at all.

Comment: return $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(200);

Comment: Still not fading, all the words just appear upon page load.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work in the return line:

```
return $(this).delay(i*200).prependTo(eachdiv).fadeIn(200);
```

Thanks for introducing me to prepend, Sindhoor!